# Jetpack compose radial menu

Tags: android, layout, menu, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to create a menu in a radial shape, or kind of a "pie" shape, but in jetpack compose.
I think I saw some example in java and canvas from about 10 years ago, that are not relevant for the compose way.

this is an example of what I'm talking about, and I'm a bit clueless on how to start:
[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75932353/how-to-check-which-arc-or-pie-chart-segment-clicked-in-jetpack-compose this will try to reduce your blockers i hope. mean check Thracian's answer.