# How do draw both end of the arc curved in same direction?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am using `drawArc` with `StrokeCap.Round` to curve the ends of arc. But it curves both ends in opposite direction (Please refer to the image of OP in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76131739/jetpack-compose-canvas-arch-extra-stroke))

Is there a straight forward way to achieve something like below image:
[image: arc with curves in same direction]