# How to Create a Labeled Arc in Jetpack Compose Using Canvas

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-canvas

I need to create the following Arc in Jetpack Compose Using Canvas but I'm really not sure how to approach it, any help or resource will be appreciated.[image]

For now I just have an empty compose project.

Comment: You can refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75903172/draw-legend-of-pie-chart-donut-chart-in-center-of-segment/75906572#75906572). And if you want arc segments to be touchable check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75932353/how-to-check-which-arc-or-pie-chart-segment-clicked-in-jetpack-compose/75932354#75932354)